# How to add locale for Arabic

Tags: java, internationalization, multilingual

I was trying to build multi-language website using JSF 2.0 using [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/)

But I am facing at this line

```
countries.put("English", Locale.ENGLISH);
countries.put("Chinese", Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I want to put it as `Arabic`, but `Locale.XXXXXXX` is not giving any support for Arab countries. What I get is some countries but NO Arabic country.

Any idea, what to do so that I can have arabic country?

Comment: **Extra:** See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29155743/597657

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to use this

```
countries.put("Arabic", new Locale("ar", "DZ"));
//or just language name for generic Arabic
new Locale("ar");
```

Where the first pair of letters means language and the second is country (region) - Algeria in this case. You can use [this](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/i18n/locales-list.shtml) link as a reference for the list of available countries and locales (I know, Roseindia sucks but this list seemed to me very useful).

Comment: I believe I have to rename welcome list to `welcome_ar_DZ`, but still its not working

Comment: Sorry, you should use different constructor, I have already edited my answer

Comment: what I did is kept all as it is... just used `countries.put("Chinese", Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);` instead of `countries.put("Arabic", Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);`

Comment: This should really work, I did the same for Czech language some time ago.