# Writing arabic letters in Java

Tags: java, arabic

I want to make it possible to write in Arabic in my server. It works but from left to right so I used that `StringUtils.reverse(_text)` now my text is written from RTL but the problem is this:
the text is written separately ( `e x a m p l e` )

In my logger

```
Log.LogChat(_type.name(), activeChar.getName(), _target, _text);
```

the chat is written correctly in my log.txt, but in the game it's written with spaces

```
// arabic chat
Say2 cs = new Say2(activeChar.getObjectId(), _type, activeChar.getName(), StringUtils.reverse(_text));
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `StringUtils.reverse` - Java handles RTL itself, so you should be able to just use the built-in support. You haven't given us nearly enough information to help you beyond that though - see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: But without  `StringUtils.reverse` the chat in game is written like our... what kind of informations i should give you exactly i'm newbie..

Comment: Well we have *no idea* how you're displaying your text, which makes it pretty much impossible to help you...

Answer (score 4):

You do NOT want to "reverse the string"!

Instead, you want to translate your application's text to Arabic ... and you want that text displayed in Arabic.  Which will automatically handle Right-to-Left.

You want to utilize Java "locales".

Check out these links:

- [How to add locale for Arabic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876287/how-to-add-locale-for-arabic)
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/locale-140624.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html
- https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/tips_for_arabic_java_desktop

Comment: This is how my java file with chat is looking for my game

[PasteBin Code](http://pastebin.com/DSK3h9UE)

Answer (score 1):

in simple,in your game,  use a jtextcomponent class and set the locale to arabic.

for more details see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/bidi.html

Comment: This is how my java file with chat is looking for my game

http://pastebin.com/DSK3h9UE do you have any ideea how to do it