# Setting Arabic numbering system locale doesn't show Arabic numbers

Tags: java, javafx, locale, javafx-8, arabic

I read this article: [JDK 8 and JRE 8 Supported Locales](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html), it stated that:

> Numbering systems can be specified by a language tag with a numbering system ID
>    
>   `╔═════════════════════╦══════════════════════╦══════════════════╗
>   ║ Numbering System ID ║   Numbering System   ║ Digit Zero Value ║
>   ╠═════════════════════╬══════════════════════╬══════════════════╣
>   ║        arab         ║ Arabic-Indic Digits  ║      \u0660      ║
>   ╚═════════════════════╩══════════════════════╩══════════════════╝`

Now, to demonstrate this, I wrote the following codes:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Locale locale = new Locale("ar", "sa", "arab");
        DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(locale);
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
        System.out.println(dfs.getZeroDigit());
        System.out.println(numberFormat.format(123));
    }
}
```

I was expecting the output to be something like:

> ٠
>   ١٢٣

However, the output is as follows:

> 0
>   123

The main purpose of this is to make JavaFX GUI showing Arabic numbers instead of English numbers as it uses the default locale (and I can set it with `Locale.setDefault(...)`).

So my question is, how to use the numbering system in the locale to show localized numbers in Java? Then, is it possible to apply it on JavaFX?

Comment: If 1, 2, 3, ... aren't Arabic digits, what are they? There are no English numbers.

Comment: I meant the digits that are used in Arabic language, like `١٢٣`.

Comment: And you right. `This is not to be confused with what the Arabs call the "Hindi numerals", namely the Eastern Arabic numerals (٠‎ - ١‎ - ٢‎ - ٣‎ -٤‎ - ٥‎ - ٦‎ - ٧‎ - ٨‎ - ٩‎) used in the Middle East` - wikipedia.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

YES, I did it! After reading [`Locale`'s JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) carefully, I was able to produce the required locale:

```
Locale arabicLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguageTag("ar-SA-u-nu-arab").build();
```

which is equivalent to:

```
Locale arabicLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("ar").setRegion("SA")
                   .setExtension(Locale.UNICODE_LOCALE_EXTENSION, "nu-arab").build();
```

---

Note that I am using something called (Unicode locale/language extension):

> UTS#35, "Unicode Locale Data Markup Language" defines optional attributes and keywords to override or refine the default behavior associated with a locale. A keyword is represented by a pair of key and type.
>
> The keywords are mapped to a BCP 47 extension value using the extension key 'u' (UNICODE_LOCALE_EXTENSION).

The extension key for numbers is (`nu`) and the value I used is (`arab`).

---

You can see a list of all extension keys [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Key_Type_Definitions).

Comment: Good job! I was exploring that track too, but missed the -u- component. I also tried searching all of the `LocaleData` entries for `\u0660`, but couldn't find it, so I'm not sure where it gets this data.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work for me. I recall seeing something about a download for additional language support. Is there an extension that needs to be installed in your JRE to add support for Arabic?

Comment: @erickson What is the output you see? `123`?

Comment: Yes, it still prints 123

Comment: @erickson OK, try other values like `nu-thai`. The output should be `๑๒๓`.

Comment: "th-TH-u-nu-thai" yields ๑๒๓

Comment: @erickson Maybe it has to do with available locales at OS level.

Comment: That could be, but Oracle claims OS only determines the default locale and that localization is platform independent.

Comment: I does not work for me i still get 123 instead of ۱۲۳

Comment: What is the name of font that you use?

Answer (score 1):

While the `Locale` in the accepted answer works well with `NumberFormat`; `DateTimeFormatter` (and prolly all other `java.time` formatters) fail to use it properly, at least before the introduction of [`localizedBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#localizedBy(java.util.Locale)) in JDK 10.

So for folks who can't use JDK 10+ and are looking to get a fully localized string representation of the date, one alternative is to do (Kotlin):

```
// code in the oh-so-sweet-and-sugary Kotlin
val locale = Locale.Builder()
                   .setLanguageTag("ar-SA-u-nu-arab")
                   .build()
val numFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale)
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MM dd", locale)
val str = formatter.format(OffsetDateTime.now())
// String.replace(Regex, noninline (MatchResult) -> CharSequence)
// this method is gold
str.replace(Regex("\\d"), {numFormat.format(it.value.toInt())}))
println(str)
```

I feel like this could be done in a better/more elegant way. If anyone has it, please do share.