# Use arabic letters with arabic numbers

Tags: java, android, locale, arabic, multilingual

It might sounds weird, but the fact is that Android handles languages really bad. Take Arabic for example :

Arabs in the east-part use arabic letters (ابجدهوز) and persian numbers (٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩).

Arabs in west-part use arabic letters (ابجدهوز) and arabic numbers (0123456789).

Android only have one kind of Arabic which is the first.

I'm looking for a way to apply the second kind in my application (use arabic letters but also arabic numbers)

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to specify the numbering system (nu) in the default locale. For example, the following locale would make the system displaying Indian numbers (٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩)

```
Locale AR_LOCALE_EAST_NUMBERS = new Locale.Builder().setLanguageTag("ar-u-nu-arab").build();
Locale.setDefault(AR_LOCALE_EAST_NUMBERS);
```

---

- See [Setting Arabic numbering system locale doesn't show Arabic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29155743/597657).

Comment: Thank you for the answer it solved my problem, I just had to put : Locale AR_LOCALE = new Locale.Builder().setLanguageTag("ar-u-nu-latn").build();

Comment: There is a problem using this solution. When you build a locale using " locale = new Locale("ar") " the screen is mirrored. Using your solution instead the screen isn't mirrored properly. There is a way to fix this behaviour?