# How to convert date from English to Arabic

Tags: java, date, arabic

I have this code

```
frame.sigdate.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/M/d").format(new Date()));
```

which reads the date from my PC with English numbers. What I want to do is convert the date to Arabic numbers.
Is there anything like `Local.ar` ?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add locale for Arabic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876287/how-to-add-locale-for-arabic)

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### java.time

```
    Locale arabicLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("ar");
    DateTimeFormatter arabicDateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
                    .withLocale(arabicLocale)
                    .withDecimalStyle(DecimalStyle.of(arabicLocale));
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Muscat"));
    System.out.println(today.format(arabicDateFormatter));
```

Output:

> ١٥‏/٤‏/٢٠١٨

The key is `withDecimalStyle`. Without this call, the formatter would still use western numerals, as in `15‏/4‏/2018`. You may want to use a more specific language tag than just `ar` for Arabic, for example `ar-BH` for Bahrain or `ar-YE` for Yemen. See the link at the bottom for possibilities. You should also insert your desired time zone where I put Asia/Muscat.

**EDIT:** The above has been tested in Java 9. Surprisingly in Java 8 it still uses western (unlocalized) digits. A possible fix (or workaround if you like) is to specify the zero digit explicitly — it will pick up the other digits from it.

```
    DecimalStyle arabicDecimalStyle
            = DecimalStyle.of(arabicLocale).withZeroDigit('٠');
    DateTimeFormatter arabicDateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
                    .withLocale(arabicLocale)
                    .withDecimalStyle(arabicDecimalStyle);
```

It’s an Arabic zero between the two apostrophes in the argument to `withZeroDigit`. Now I get this output on Java 8:

> ١٥/٠٤/١٨

It’s usually a good idea to use the built-in locale specific formats as I do with `ofLocalizedDate` in both snippets above. If you need finer control over the format, use `ofPattern` instead. For example, to get yyyy/mm/dd format:

```
    DateTimeFormatter arabicDateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM/dd", arabicLocale)
                    .withDecimalStyle(arabicDecimalStyle);
```

Output:

> ٢٠١٨/٠٤/١٥

The reason why the format changed from Java 8 to Java 9 is that Java has changed the defaults for where the locale data come from, including the built-in localized date and time formats. You can get the Java 9 format already in Java 8 by setting a system property, for example like this:

```
    System.setProperty("java.locale.providers", "CLDR,JRE,SPI");
```

With this change the first code snippet above gives the same output on Java 8 as on Java 9:

> ١٥‏/٤‏/٢٠١٨

The important detail here is that `CLDR` goes first in the property string. And the advantages are you don’t need to specify your own format pattern string, localization to other locales is straightforward and users won’t be surprised by a change in behaviour once you switch to Java 9 or later.

I am using and recommending `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. The `SimpleDateFormat` class that you used in the question is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. IMHO you should avoid it completely. The modern API is so much nicer to work with.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [List of supported locales in Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java8locales-2095355.html)

Comment: Some how the my output is (15/04/18), why?

Comment: It works just like magic!! Just one more question, how to change the format to (yyyy/mm/dd)?

Comment: Thank you very much, you made my day!

Comment: I think I found a better fix for the Arabic numerals in Java 8, but which you prefer is also a matter of taste. See my latest edit. You can also combine CLDR with your own format pattern if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/MM/yyyy");

String date = "16/08/2011";
Locale arabicLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("ar-SA");
DateTimeFormatter arabicDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(arabicLocale).withDecimalStyle(DecimalStyle.of(arabicLocale));

LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Muscat"));
today = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);

String dat = today.format(arabicDateFormatter);
System.out.println(dat);
```

**out put  ١٦‏/٨‏/٢٠١١**

Answer (score 0):

try below approch

```
java.util.Locale locale = new java.util.Locale("ar");
java.text.DecimalFormat df = (java.text.DecimalFormat)
java.text.DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dateTimeObjectInUTC = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTimeZone dateTimeZoneObject = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Riyadh");

java.util.Locale locale = new Locale("ar","SA");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle("FF").withLocale(locale).withZone(dateTimeZoneObject);
String output = formatter.print(dateTimeObjectInUTC);
```

This should help!

I am using Joda-Time. Please refer to the Jodatime documentation. [`DateTimeZone` documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html), for example.

Comment: Are you using Joda-Time? It’s better than `SimpleDateFormat` and its outdated friends. `java.time` is still better. “Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310).” Quoted from the Joda-Time homepage.

Comment: Never used it before, I'll definitely take that advice!

Comment: [Link to Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Enjoy.

Comment: what is "DateTimeZone"?

Comment: Please refer to the Jodatime documentation - http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html